# Do you need to complete both routes indicated on a destination card?

Tags: ticket-to-ride

In Ticket to Ride UK, there is a destination card from Glasgow to France that has two routes to France.  The points on the card are 19.  If a player completes both routes to France that are indicated on this destination card, would the player receive 38 points?  Or is the player required to complete both destinations for 19 points?  This is not clear.

[image: Glasgow to France Card]

Answer (score 14):

You only have to make the required connection (Glasgow to France) once for 19 points. Like all destination tickets; a single ticket cannot be scored multiple times, even if you connect the locations via multiple routes.

The reason that the ticket shows multiple routes is because France is a country, as opposed to a city. In the base Ticket to Ride game, destination tickets are only between two cities. But in this expansion, some of them include a country instead of a city. The country behaves differently because there are multiple spaces within that country. So instead of having to connect a specific place to another specific place; you just have to connect a specific place to one of those 2 places within France.

This is mentioned somewhat in the Ticket to Ride: Marklin rules:

> Some Destination Ticket include the name of a city and a country name. Each route leading to a country
>   is a dead end and cannot be used to link two cities.

Comment: It's also in the rules for TtR:Switzerland: " To complete a city-to-country ticket you must connect from the city name on the ticket to one of the countries listed on the ticket. [...] The points earned at game's end are those of the highest scoring connection completed from among the possible country destinations marked on the ticket."

Answer (score 8):

**You only need to connect the two locations using *any route* in order to claim the points.** Once you've connected the two locations, the Destination Ticket is considered complete and you can claim the points at the end of the game. A Destination Ticket can only be completed and scored once, even if you complete it multiple times through different routes.

I believe this is cleared up in the [rules](https://cdn1.daysofwonder.com/tickettoride/en/img/tt_africa_rules_2015.pdf) for the Heart of Africa expansion, which has a similar situation with Madagascar:

> Madagascar is represented by 2 locations on the map; Tickets to Madagascar can be completed by reaching either of these 2 locations, even if the other location isn’t reached.

This could also be applied to France in the United kingdom expansion. The question about the Glasgow-France ticket has also been [asked over on BoardGameGeek](https://boardgamegeek.com/thread/1579702/routes-france-need-connect-both-locations-or-no) and answered the same.

Comment: I don't think this is actually clear based on the base rules. In the base game, as it says, a destination ticket includes the name of two CITIES. And the drawing on the card shows those 2 Cities and the shortest way they could be connected generally. But here, we have 3 spots shown on the card, not 2; and it shows a country instead of a city.

Comment: Yes, if I read it correctly, the second half that you edited in is what really answers the question. I don't think the question was ever asking about if you have to specifically follow the city-to-city routes that are shown on the destination tickets.

Comment: @GendoIkari Yeah. It didn't occur to me that there would be any confusion relating to connecting both routes. In my head, that was covered by the first portion of my answer, wherein you only need to connect the two locations to score points, regardless of how you connect them. Thanks for the comment that led to the improvement.

Comment: so if you complete both routes from Glasgow to France, you get 38 points?  In T-T-R Switzerland there are a few cards with multiple city to country routes, each of which have their own point value shown on the card.  So the player collects the points associated with each completed route.  But this card shows only one point count, not separate ones for each route to France.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @MaryAnn No. You'll only score the points one time for a total of 19 points. For Destination tickets that only have two locations to connect, you don't score points for each time they're connected. You only score them once.

Comment: I don't understand your first (bolded) sentence. There are three cities on the card, which two do you need to connect?

Comment: @MaryAnn There are only two locations on the card: Glasgow and France. You only need to connect those two locations.

Comment: @MaryAnn I think you're getting hung up on the picture. The Destination Ticket requires you to connect two locations. As long as you do that, regardless of how you do it, you score the points on the card. In this case, there happens to be two different ways to complete that Destination Ticket: the east and west points for France.

Comment: The problem is that the picture on the card is NOT clear by itself. It shows 3 locations on the card; you need the rulebook (the heart of Africa rules really) to understand that 2 of those locations both count as "France", and it doesn't matter which one you connect to.

Comment: @GendoIkari I disagree. The card says to connect Glasgow to France. The picture is inconsequential in how a player does this. If every Destination Ticket in TTR had no picture, it wouldn't change the locations that need to be connected. The picture may not be clear, but it doesn't need to be. I agree that the ruling in the Heart of Africa Expansion on Madagascar provides the clearest way to treat this case.

Comment: @SocioMatt If every card had no picture, it would be fine. The problem is that all the other cards have a picture that shows just 2 locations; the 2 that need to be connected. This card breaks that convention by showing 3 locations; of which 2 of them are alternate options within France.